# Update/Upgrade Django 1.8 project code to Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a large django project built in 1.8 with about 14 apps and a large amount of dependencies.

I already have a good idea about how I'm going to update the 2.7 code to 3.6 or possibly just make it compatible with both, however, I'm not sure what is the best practice and most efficient way to refactor/upgrade the django framework to 2.0 from 1.8.

Bare in mind this thousands of lines of code so efficiency in terms of work is crucial.

Thanks in advance for all suggestions!

Comment: I would recommend first upgrading your Django 1.8 installation to use Python 3.6, then upgrade Django one version at a time while reading the release notes for the new version. You can also see deprecation warnings with `python -Wall manage.py runserver`, and once you've eliminated all deprecation warnings and gotten external dependencies working, you should be good to upgrade Django to the next version. So go to 1.9 first, then 1.10, etc.

Comment: I considered this would be the most sensible also initially but thought it might have been a longer but safer way to go around it especially with all the package dependencies.

Comment: As everyone has generally recommended I'll update the django version by version to 1.11.x LTS, then separately update that python once I improve my test suite. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First of all you should update all your packeges to support python
   3.6 and Django 2.0.
2. In all of your `urls.py` you shoud change all `url` fuctions to `path` or `re_path`.

   `url('some/', Create.as_view()) # old version`

   `path('some/', Create.as_view()) # new version`

If you use `namespace` in your main `urls.py` you should add app_name to every app's `urls.py`.

```
app_name = ‘app-name’
```

3. Search your project for `is_authenticated()` and change it everywhere to `is_authenticated`. It's now an property, not a method. Do the same for `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`, replace it with `from django.urls import reverse`.
4. Now every `ForeignKey` model field has to have a `on_delete` argument. Like this:

`on_delete=models.CASCADE on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING on_delete=models.SET_NULL`

[Check the official documentation on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#arguments)

Then make migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

5. Next, in `settings.py` you need to change your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to `MIDDLEWAR`
   Then update `MIDDLEWAR` to match this:

   `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'`
6. If you use your own middleware in your project, you should inherit from `MiddlewareMixin`, not from `object`. So you have to import it

   `from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin`

**[Check out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/upgrade-version/) the official docuntation for much more information.** Try to do it first next time.